# NodeJs passport local strategy authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I want to create pretty simple authentication in my NodeJs web application using passport localStrategy.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  console.log('before auth');
  passport.authenticate('local'),
    function(req, res) {
      // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
      // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
      // res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
      console.log('auth is ok');
    }
});
```

What I've done:

1. I have web form with fields login and password and action = "/login"
2. In routers in my application I have route for login like this

After form submitted I can see in my console "before auth" which means that router is working. But I cant see "auth is ok" which means that authentication does not succeeded.

How can I implement passport.authenticate function in my application?

Comment: Perhaps you should start with [the example code](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example).

Comment: @robertklep Thank you. Your example is working for me. I'll try to compare your and my code and try try find where is my fault...

Comment: @robertklep can you tell me if what is in the link you gave us, that when ever the author uses `cb` I could substitute the words `done`. `done` is used a lot in the documentation. I was wondering if `done` and `cb` was interchangeable

Comment: @jackblank yes, they are. It's just a variable name, you can name it anything you want, but `cb`, `callback` or `done` are the most common I think (to signify that the argument is a callback function that gets called when an async operation is done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password' 
  }, function(email, password, next) {
    //do what you want here
    //call next(pass parameter here (i.e error, object)
  }));


app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
      console.log('before auth');
      passport.authenticate('local', function(err, anotherthing){
      //err and anotherThing are the parameters send by strategy (next function). 

       });
    });
```

Also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400758/comprehensive-tutorial-for-nodejs-passport-local-strategy-setup). For more details to accomplish this. Kind regards

Comment: Sorry that my question was not clear enough. I need some help in implementation local strategy implementation. In other words what I have to do in order to authenticate user in my web application?

Comment: @AlexZhulin I've updated the answer to help you see how to implement Strategy. Also posted a link to another topic with links to help you.

Comment: I added   passport.use(new localStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'passwd'
      },
      function(username, password, next) {
        console.log('LocalStrategy');
        next();
      }
  )); as you suggested but it seems that this peace of code didn't get invoked because I cant see in my log 'LocalStrategy' message... Could you suggest my where I'm wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: that code it was only example how you should use Strategy...I don't know how you're using your code. I just show you the path you should seek...the link I've posted helps you to define how to implement local authentication...if you need further help, you have to post the code you're using. ;)